# Is it valid C++ to cast an rvalue to a const pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

In a moment of haste, needing a pointer to an object to pass to a function. I took the address of an unnamed temporary object and to my surprise it compiled (the original code had warnings turned further down and lacked the const correctness present in the example below). Curious, I set up a controlled environment with warnings all the way up and treating warnings as errors in Visual Studio 2013.

Consider the following code:

```
class Contrived {
  int something;
};

int main() {
  const Contrived &r  = Contrived();                    // this is well defined even in C++03, the object lives until r goes out of scope
  const Contrived *p1 = &r;                             // compiles fine, given the type of r this should be fine. But is it considering r was initialized with an rvalue?
  const Contrived *p2 = &(const Contrived&)Contrived(); // this is handy when calling functions, is it valid? It also compiles
  const int       *p3 = &(const int&)27;                // it works with PODs too, is it valid C++?

  return 0;
}
```

The three pointer initializations are all more or less the same thing. The question is, are these initializations valid C++ under C++03, C++11, or both? I ask about C++11 separately in case something changed, considering that a lot of work was put in around rvalue references. It may not seem worthwhile to assign these values such as in the above example, but it's worth noting this could save some typing if such values are being passed to a function taking constant pointers and you don't have an appropriate object lying around or feel like making a temporary object on a line above.

**EDIT:**
Based on the answers the above is valid C++03 and C++11. I'd like to call out some additional points of clarification with regard to the resulting objects' lifetimes.

Consider the following code:

```
class Contrived {
  int something;
} globalClass;
int globalPOD = 0;

template <typename T>
void SetGlobal(const T *p, T &global) {
  global = *p;
}

int main() {
  const int *p1 = &(const int&)27;
  SetGlobal<int>(p1, globalPOD);              // does *p still exist at the point of this call?

  SetGlobal<int>(&(const int&)27, globalPOD); // since the rvalue expression is cast to a reference at the call site does *p exist within SetGlobal

  // or similarly with a class
  const Contrived *p2 = &(const Contrived&)Contrived();
  SetGlobal<Contrived>(p2, globalClass);
  SetGlobal<Contrived>(&(const Contrived&)Contrived(), globalClass);

  return 0;
}
```

The question is are either or both of the calls to SetGlobal valid, in that they are passing a pointer to an object that will exist for the duration of the call under the C++03 or C++11 standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `rvalue` is a type of expression, not a type of object.  We're talking about the *temporary object* created by `Contrived()`, it doesn't make sense to say "this object is an rvalue".  The expression that created the object is an rvalue expression, but that's different.

Even though the object in question is a temporary object, its lifetime has been extended. It's perfectly fine to perform operations on the object using the identifier `r` which denotes it. The expression `r` is an lvalue.

`p1` is OK. On the `p2` and `p3` lines, the lifetime of the reference ends at the end of that full-expression, so the temporary object's lifetime also ends at that point. So it would be undefined behaviour to use `p2` or `p3` on subsequent lines. The initializing expression could be used as an argument to a function call though, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Yes, an rvalue refers to expressions not objects. It's a subtle difference but one I want to be more precise/correct therewith. I didn't think about the scope of the reference ending (since it's just a cast). Or perhaps I thought the object's lifetime may again be extended by the const pointer (since a reference is just a pointer under the hood and the reference is defined to extend the lifetime of the object). It seems this is not so?

Comment: So, one more questions or point of clarification. You said "the initializing expression could be used as an argument to a function call." So, I could do something like this? `void fn(const int *p){global = *p;}` and `fn(&(const int&)27);` and the "object" `p` points to would be guaranteed to exist within the function?

Comment: In the language definition, a reference isn't a "pointer under the hood". It's an alias for a variable.  It turns out that if passing a parameter to a function by reference, then using the variable's address is often the simplest way to do it; but that doesn't change the language definition, which specifically talks about const references extending lifetime, and not pointers to const.

Comment: `An rvalue is a type of expression` No, rvalue is a "value category". It's not a "type" at all.

Comment: I've updated my question with these additional points of object lifetime that your answer already addresses, as well as correcting the rvalue terminology. The terminology used fits with the value category or expression definitions of an rvalue that are still under discussion in the comments here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, this is the English word "type", not the C++ language term. Overloaded words!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Almost as bad as overloaded operators ;p

Answer (score 1):

The first one is good: the expression `r` is not in fact an rvalue.

The other two are technically valid, too, but be aware that pointers become dangling at the end of the full expression (at the semicolon), and any attempt to use them would exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

While it is perfectly legal to pass an rvalue by `const&`, you have to be aware that your code ends up with invalidated pointers in `p2` and `p3`, since the lifetime of the objects that they point is over.

To exemplify this, consider the following code that is often used to pass a temporary by reference:

```
template<typename T>
void pass_by_ref(T const&);
```

A function like this can be called with an lvalue or rvalue as its argument (and often is). Inside that function you can obviously take the reference of your argument - it is just a reference to a `const` object after all... You are basically doing the exact same thing without the help of a function.

In fact, in C++11, you can go one step further and obtain a non-const pointer to an temporary:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type* example(T&& t)
{
    return &t;
}
```

Note that the object the return value points to will only still exist if this function is called with an lvalue (since its argument will turn out to be `typename remove_reference<T>::type& &&` which is `typename remove_reference<T>::type&`).

Comment: If the function is called with an rvalue temporary, it's not valid C++, since it's disallowed to take the address of an rvalue.